# Why is rename command missing from macOS?

Tags: macos, command-line, bash

I usually rename files and directories with the `mv` command. I'm reading a book on bash shell that mentions the `rename` command. When I executed `man rename` a man page was shown. However, when I entered `rename` on bash shell, it reported:

```
-bash: rename: command not found
```

I did some research and discovered that you can install the `rename` command with Homebrew.

- Is there any good reason not to install it with Homebrew?
- Is there anything you can do with the `rename` command that you can't do with the `mv` command?

I'm also curious to know if there is a known explanation for why the `rename` command doesn't exist in the first place. And why is there a man page for a command that does not exist?

Comment: After some more searching, I discovered that the reason there is a man page is because it is documenting a BSD system call, not the command. My question asks about installing this utility with homebrew, so it is applicable to the mac.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the default install of macOS, rename man page is available in the section 2. As you can notice from the man page, rename is not a command but a BSD system call.

The Homebrew formula named rename is a Perl script. You should be fine with installing it. In-fact it can give you much more flexibility than plain mv command.

After you have installed rename utility via Homebrew, running `man rename` will show the man page for the installed utility and not the BSD system call.

> I'm also curious to know if there is a known explanation for why the command does not exist in the first place.

[rename](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ren_(command)) is not a standard Unix command.

> And why is there a man page for a command that does not exist?

As mentioned above, the man page present refers to the system call by the same name.

Comment: Just saw your answer after installing it with homebrew. Now `man rename` bring up documentation for the "User Contributed Perl Documentation" for the utility.

Answer (score 1):

With `rename` command you can search and replace string in multiple files in simply way:

```sh
rename 's/oldstring/newtext/' file00*
```

It's really useful. With `mv` you cannot do the same. Unless you get loop to work:

```sh
for file in file00*; do new=${file/oldstring/newtext}; mv —- "$file" "$new"; done
```

Comment: I found the zmv in the "new" default Zsh shell to do most of the filename rename tasks I need. Don't even need brew install rename. Just "autoload -U zmv" and you are ready. "zmv -n '(**/)(*).js' '$1$2.ts'" will preview what it is about to do, and remove -n to get it done.

Answer (score -1):

You can install using brew https://brewinstall.org/Install-rename-on-Mac-with-Brew/

Hope this solves your problem.